# Pine script - How to retain variable value between bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a variable and retain its value between bar iterations. Here's an example snippet:

My question is... Is this the correct way to retain CashValue and OrderQtty between bars? Is there a more reliable way of doing so?

```
Indicator('My script')
CashValue = 1000.00  // starting cash value
OrderQtty = 0        // starting asset value
...
EntryCondition = .... //Some entry condition to buy asset
ExitCondition = ....  //Some exit condition to sell asset
...

if EntryCondition
    OrderQtty := math.floor(CashValue/close)
    Alert('Buy '+str.tostring(OrderQtty), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
else if ExitCondition
    Alert('Sell all', alert.freq_once_per_bar) 
    CashValue := OrderQtty*close
else
    na
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`var`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_var) operator will allow the variable store its value between bars

```
var CashValue = 1000.00  // starting cash value
var OrderQtty = 0        // starting asset value
```